# Wordpress Admin side Filter and Sorting are not working properly

Tags: wordpress, post, filter, short, wp-admin

Wordpress Admin side Filter and Sorting are not working properly at edit.php page(Post List Page). I have a large amount of posts (More than 1 lakes). It's Core Functionality of Wordpress. How can I solve this? I tried a lot. Please Provide me proper solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Do you mean "sorting"?

Comment: sorting and Filter Both.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you try to sort/filter?

Comment: No-errors in colsole. I have "xyz" category with 12 posts. but It shows 10 posts only.